# Geogebra Javascript - How to default no caption for every math object created in graphic view?

Tags: javascript, geogebra

```
function ggbOnInit(){
      ggbApplet.registerAddListener("onAdd");
}

function onAdd(name){
    setLabelVisible(name,0);
}
```

---

The above code isn't working in the global javascript setting in geogebra. What i want is simple, i want to create objects without captions. it seems to me that geogebra default captions. 
please advise.

Comment: Per the JavaScript documentation the method should work. Things to consider; Context: It appears onAdd is calling setLabelVisible(name,0); without targeting the applet. I.E. try ggbApplet.setLabelVisible(name,0);. Timing: consider when onAdd is being called, if actually being called at all, and at the right time. Understanding: Debug statements can be placed in the function to determine when it fired and what the name parameter delivered as a string name. I prefer the Chrome debugger. Firefox's is excellent too. Using one can help. See: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

Comment: I am using the above code internally, in the geogebra global setting.  Does it matter if I don't specify what target applet is?

Comment: Yes, the documentation stipulates that a ggbApplet name has been defined regardless if in a browser or exported applet.  "in this document we presume that object is stored in variable called ggbApplet." See: https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:JavaScript#Obtaining_the_Applet_Object

Answer (score 0):

> setLabelVisible(name,0);

should be

> ggbApplet.setLabelVisible(name, false);

Note that it's much easier to just set in the options menus:
Options -> Labelling -> No New Objects